# $p:E\to B$ is fibration then $p_*:map(X,E)\to map(X,B)$ is fibration as well.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, proof-verification, category-theory, fibration

> $p:E\to B$ is fibration then for $X$ being compactly generated weakly Hausdorff space  $p_*:map(X,E)\to map(X,B)$ is fibration as well.

We'd like to show that for any $Y$ and continuous $f$ and homotopy $H$ exists lift $\tilde H$ s.t. following diagram is commutative:
$$
\begin{matrix}
Y & \xrightarrow{f} & map(X,E) \\
\left\downarrow{i_0}\vphantom{\int}\right. & \nearrow{\tilde H}\vphantom{\int}& \left\downarrow{p_*}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
Y\times I&  \xrightarrow{H} & map(X,B)
\end{matrix}
$$
My attempt was to construct $\tilde H$ using fact that $p$ is fibration, namely for every element $y \in Y$ (which can be done because $Y$ is set):

$$
\begin{matrix}
X & \xrightarrow{f(y)} & E \\
\left\downarrow{i_0}\vphantom{\int}\right. & \nearrow{\tilde H(y,\square)}\vphantom{\int}& \left\downarrow{p}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
X\times I&  \xrightarrow{H(y,\square)} & B
\end{matrix}
$$

where $H(y,\square): (x,t)\mapsto H(y,t)(x)$. Then homotopy given by formula $\tilde H: (y,t) \mapsto \tilde H(y,t)$ gives us demanded lift in first diagram. **Is it correct proof?** Where did I use (indirectly) **assumption about $X$ being CGWH space** or one can get rid of it? My suspicion suggest that this assumption could have used if we had consider all those diagrams in $\mathcal{Top}$ category not $\mathcal{Set}$ (I don't know in which category this problem should hold but the assumption suggests that it may be $\mathcal{Top}$). I'm not familiar with CGWH spaces so I'd be glad for stressing where this assumption plays a role.

Comment: Use the adjunction between $X \times (-)$ and $\mathrm{map}(X, -)$.  (The category of compactly generated Hausdorff spaces is cartesian closed.)

Comment: @Adeel I think I see your point; $map(X,-)$ will save limit but is there any definition of fibration containing limit which I could map through $map(X,-)$ to use this fact? Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question, but here is what I meant: applying this adjunction to the first square in your question will give you another square, which you will be able to lift using the lifting property of $p$.  This lift will then, by the same adjunction, correspond to a lift in your original square.

Comment: You can see this question and its answers for some more details: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92425/passing-pullbacks-through-adjunction  The setting there is the category of simplicial sets, but the argument is completely formal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the comment of Adeel, you have to exploit the following easy fact about orthogonal classes of arrows in categories:

Let $F\dashv G$ be two adjoint functors between categories $\mathcal{C}\leftrightarrows\mathcal{D}$; then $Ff\perp g$ in the category $\mathcal D$ (i.e., $Ff$ has the LLP with respect to $g$ in $\cal D$) if and only if $f\perp Gg$ in the category $\cal C$.

Now apply this to $X\times(-)\dashv Map(X,-)$; the exercise is not finished (it remains showing that $X\times i$ is again an acyclic cofibration!) but I think it's the best hint to work conceptually.

Comment: I can hardly see why $Ff \perp g$ iff $f \perp Gg$. It means that there exists proper diagonal in $$
\begin{matrix}
FD_2 & \xrightarrow{u} & C_1 \\
\left\downarrow{Fg}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{f}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
FD_1&  \xrightarrow{v} & C_2
\end{matrix}
$$ iff there exists diagonal in 
$$
\begin{matrix}
D_2 & \xrightarrow{u'} & GC_1 \\
\left\downarrow{g}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{Gf}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
D_1&  \xrightarrow{v'} & GC_2
\end{matrix}
$$ how to apply adjointness here? We only know that our diagonals on left are bijective to the right.

Comment: I mean that adjointness gives us a bijection between $hom(FD_1,C_1)$ and $hom(D_1,G_C1)$ so clearly lift $p : FD_1 \to C_1$ corresponds to some lift $p':D_1 \to GC_1$ but what about comutativity of the second square after obtaining such arrow $p'$ (or maybe it is wrong way to show that lemma at all?)? I tried to work with naturality of $hom(F\square,\square) \to hom(\square, G \square)$ to obtain that but I couldn't prove that :(. I'd appreciate an explanation or just a hint.

Comment: I try to sketch what you have to do, do tell me where you get into troubles. 1. Show that the set $LP(Ff, g)$ of lifting problems for $Ff$ and $g$ and $LP(f, Gg)$ are in bijection. (Show that the bijection is induced by the adjinction map). 2. Deduce that the mates under the adjunction correspond also to solutions for the two kinds of lifting problems

Comment: Hey, could you take a look at the answer I just wrote? :) Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

My attempt to prove categorical remarks of Adeel and tetrapharmakon from the comments was too long for the comment hence I'm posting it as an answer.

> **(Lemma)** Let $F\dashv G$ be two adjoint functors between categories $\mathcal{C}\leftrightarrows\mathcal{D}$; then $Ff\perp g$ in the category $\mathcal D$ (i.e., $Ff$ has the LLP with respect to $g$ in $\cal D$) if and only if $f\perp Gg$ in the category $\cal C$. (where $f:C_1\to C_2$, $g:D_2 \to D_1$).

In other words there exists an arrow $FC_2 \to D_2$ making following diagram commutative:
$$
\begin{matrix}
FC_1 & \xrightarrow{u} & D_2 \\
\left\downarrow{Ff}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{g}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
FC_2&  \xrightarrow{v} & D_1
\end{matrix}
$$

if and only if there exists an arrow $C_2 \to GD_2$ making following diagram commutative:
$$
\begin{matrix}
C_1 & \xrightarrow{u'} & GD_2 \\
\left\downarrow{f}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{Gg}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
C_2&  \xrightarrow{v'} & GD_1
\end{matrix}
$$

But $F\dashv G$ means that following diagram is commutative:

$$
\begin{matrix}
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_2,D_2) & \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_2,GD_2) \\
\left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{D}(Ff,g)}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{C}(f,Gg)}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_1,D_1)&  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_1,GD_1)
\end{matrix}
$$

Once again from adjunction (i.e. isomorphism between hom-sets) we know that to every $u' \in hom_\mathcal{D}(C_1,GD_2)$ corresponds uniquely some $u \in hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_1,D_2)$. Similarly let $v \in hom_\mathcal{C}(FC_2, D_1)$ be a morphism corresponding  to $v' \in hom_\mathcal{C}(C_2,GD_1)$. Let's suppose that there exists $\eta:FC_2 \to D_2$ making the very first with diagram commutative for preceding choice of morphisms $u, v$ and $\phi:C_2 \to GD_2$ morphism corresponding to it by adjunction.

$$
\begin{matrix}
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_2,D_2) & \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_2,GD_2) \\
\left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{D}(Ff,id)}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{C}(f,id)}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_1,D_2)&  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_1,GD_2) \\
\left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{D}(id,g)}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{C}(id,Gg)}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_1,D_1)&  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_1,GD_1)
\end{matrix}
$$
for setting above we have:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\eta & \xrightarrow{\simeq} & \phi \\
\left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
\eta \circ Ff = u &  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & \phi \circ f = u' \\
\left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
g\circ u = g \circ \eta \circ Ff&  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & Gg \circ \phi \circ f = Gg \circ u'
\end{matrix}
$$

Similarly:
$$
\begin{matrix}
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_2,D_2) & \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_2,GD_2) \\
\left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{D}(id,Gg)}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{C}(id,g)}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_2,D_1)&  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_2,GD_1) \\
\left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{D}(Ff,id)}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{hom_\mathcal{C}(f,id)}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
hom_\mathcal{D}(FC_1,D_1)&  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & hom_\mathcal{C}(C_1,GD_1)
\end{matrix}
$$
so:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\eta & \xrightarrow{\simeq} & \phi \\
\left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
g \circ \eta  = v &  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & Gg \circ \phi = v' \\
\left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
v \circ f = g \circ \eta \circ Ff&  \xrightarrow{\simeq} & Gg \circ \phi \circ f =  u' \circ f
\end{matrix}
$$
in the same way we can show that the existence of lifting in second diagram implies existence of lifting in the first and hence the thesis of lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Solution which I came up with today:

Let's recall the definition of a cocylinder $P(p)$ i.e. the pullback of such diagram:
$$
\begin{matrix}
P(p) & \xrightarrow{p'} & P(B) \\
\left\downarrow{p_0}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{p_0}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
E&  \xrightarrow{p} & B
\end{matrix}
$$
(where $p':(e,\omega)\mapsto p \circ \omega$).
We may apply this for object $P(E)$ and morphisms $p_* :P(E) \to P(B)$, $p_0:P(E)\to E$ obtaining a unique arrow $\bar p :P(E) \to P(p)$. However we know that $p$ is fibration iff $\exists s:P(p) \to P(E)$ such that $ \bar p  \circ s = id_{P(p)}$.

Let's map our diagram against functor $map(X, \square)$ obtaining:

$$
\begin{matrix}
map(X,P(p)) & \xrightarrow{p'_*} & map(X,P(B)) \\
\left\downarrow{p_{0*}}\vphantom{\int}\right. & & \left\downarrow{p_{0*}}\vphantom{\int}\right.\\
map(X,E)&  \xrightarrow{p_*} & map(X,B)
\end{matrix}
$$

There exists a unique arrow $ \bar p_* : P(map(X,E)) \to map(X,P(p))$ since $map(X,\square)$ preserves limits (hence pullbacks as well) (I'm cheating here a little because we know that there exists *some* unique arrow not necessarily $\bar p_*$ but it is isomorphic to $\bar p_*$ so let's stick to $\bar p_*$) but moreover in our CGWH category: $$map(X,P(B)) = map(X,map(I,B))\cong map(I \times X,B)\cong map(X \times I,B) \cong map(I ,map(X, B)) = P(map(X,B))$$ so $map(X,P(p))$ is cocylinder $P(p_*)$ and now we have only to show that there exists $s' : map(X,P(p)) \to P(map(X,E))$ such that $\bar p _* \circ s' = id_{P(p_*)}$. Surprisingly $s' = map(X,s)$ works like charm since $\bar p_* \circ map(X, s) = map(X,\bar p \circ s) = map(X,id_{P(p)}) = id_{map(X,P(p))} = id_{P(p_*)}$.